# DB2 MERGE statement error

Tags: merge, db2, token, using

I have tried the following with a couple of variations but I continue to get errors. Any way to get this fixed. DB2 10.1 (DB2 for z/OS V10)

For the following

```
MERGE INTO TRGT t
USING SRC s
ON (t.ACCTID=s.ACCTID AND s.SEQID=123)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
MyFlag = 'Y'
```

Error:
An unexpected token "SRC" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "(".  SQLSTATE=42601

SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104

---

However for the following

```
MERGE INTO TRGT t
USING (SELECT SEQID, ACCTID FROM SRC WHERE SEQID=123) s
ON (t.ACCTID=s.ACCTID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
MyFlag = 'Y'
```

Error:
The use of the reserved word "SELECT" following "" is not valid.  Expected tokens may include:  "VALUES".  SQLSTATE=42601

SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -199

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately (and I never understood why), in DB2 for z/OS, you can't use a table as a source for the [`MERGE`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_merge.htm), you can only use a VALUES clause. Additionally, if you want to merge multiple rows, you have to use [host variable arrays](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_dataceesshostvariablearrays.htm), and specify the number of values are in your array.

```sql
MERGE INTO TRGT t
USING (VALUES (:param1, :param2) FOR :paramNumRows) s
   ON (t.ACCTID=s.ACCTID)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET MyFlag = 'Y'
```

Comment: @RajuRaju: if my response answers your question, please "accept" it (there should be a checkmark below the voting buttons to do this). You can also vote the answer up, as well.