# SQL update to partially synchronise two columns in two different tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables:

```
Table 1: S490JR
USER         ROCOMP ROSUPC  REFID          QREADSTAT                 
MARQUEE  AQUA     E31       4081200201      1                        
MARQUEE  AQUA     E31       4102700301      1                        
TENNYSON AQUA     E34       4102101701      0                        
TENNYSON AQUA     E34       4102704501      0                        


    and table2: AB27PR                                         

USER      XCCOMP    XCSUPN  XEFID        XREADSTAT                   
MARQUEE AQUA      E31       4081200201  0                          
MARQUEE AQUA      E31       4081200201  0                          
MARQUEE GBRT      A183    50129004    0                          
MARQUEE GBRT      A205    50126025    0
```

If there is a match on S490JR.USER to  AB27PR.USER, and ROCOMP to XCCOMP and REFID to XEFID then I would like to update the XREADSTAT value with that of QREADSTAT only if XREADSTAT is 0 and QREADSTAT is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `MERGE`

```
merge into AB27PR AB
    using (select USER, ROCOMP,REFID
             from S490JR
            where QREADSTAT =1) SR
    on
       (AB.USER= SR.ORDER_ID
        AND AB.XCCOMP = SR.ROCOMP
        AND AB.XEFID = SR.REFID )
    when matched 
     and AB.XREADSTAT = 1
    then update set XREADSTAT = SR.QREADSTAT;
```

Comment: I think your solution runs into the same problem as this for DB2:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734001/db2-merge-statement-error)

Comment: and I'm not sure how to integrate it with your solution

Comment: @TobyDerrum,  What platform and version of DB2?  The above would work fine on DB2 for IBM i and DB2 LUW...it appears that only DB2 for z/OS has the limitation described at the link you provided..

Comment: @Charles Unfortunately it is on the AS400 or z/os. I don't have the exact DB2 version but I know it to be at least a decade old.

Comment: @Charles The version of AS/400 is 7.1

Comment: @Charles The version of AS/400 is  actually OS 6.1 and I gather the merge statement comes in at 7.1.

Comment: @TobyDerrum Yes, MERGE is not a  part of 6.1, added for 7.1.

Comment: @user2338816 thanks for your help and sorry for the wild goose chase. My own access to the As400 was limited.