# SQL merge on in DB2 running on AS400, 6.1

Tags: sql, merge, db2, ibm-midrange

The following query does not work in DB2 which is running on the As400. I've read of similar [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734001/db2-merge-statement-error) but am unsure how to modify my query accordingly.

```
merge into AB27PR AB
    using (select USER, ROCOMP,REFID, QREADSTAT
             from S490JR
            where QREADSTAT =1) SR
    on
       (AB.USER= SR.USER
        AND AB.XCCOMP = SR.ROCOMP
        AND AB.XEFID = SR.REFID )
    when matched 
     and AB.XREADSTAT = 0
    then update set XREADSTAT = SR.QREADSTAT;
```

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: @Siyual I get a message to say Error: [SQL0104] Token MERGE was not valid.

Comment: Check the manual for your version of AS/400 to see if `MERGE` is supported.

Comment: @mustaccio The version of AS/400 is 7.1 and it supports MERGE. I'd  guess the problem does relate to the link I posted.

Comment: I don't see how DB2 for z/OS limitations might be relevant on an IBM i system.

Comment: What is the rest of the error message where it tells what the Valid tokens are?  Where are you running this?  Do you have a prior statement that isn't terminated with ;?

Comment: Running 7.1 here and use merge all the time.  I don't see any reference to a particular TR or DB Group PTF here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-db2merge/ .  Where are you running the statement?  If in Run SQL Scripts, do you have a statement above you forgot to end with a semicolon?

Comment: @ScottMildenberger. The rest says  `Error: [SQL0104] Token MERGE was not valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER.
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104`

Comment: Can you paste into the green-screen STRSQL or the gui Run SQL Scripts and see if you get the same error.  The error seems to imply that you are not at 7.1 or at a level that was before MERGE was added.

Comment: @Charles I am running the statement inside SQL Squirrel before I copy it into ibatis, I have tried it with and without a semi-colon on the end. it is the only statement I am running.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger I will try and get access via green-screen and will post back. Is there a possible alternative without the use of MERGE ?

Comment: Is that the actual MERGE statement you want to run, or is it a trimmed down example that illustrates the error? It doesn't seem to actually accomplish anything even if it completes successfully.

Comment: @user2338816 It is rather meant to carry the condition `and AB.XREADSTAT = 0` and I've update the original post which should see it accomplish something now.

Comment: Can you temporarily replace the MERGE statement with a simple UPDATE that will do nothing, e.g., with "WHERE 1 <> 1" or similar? If it's put into the same place, it should give the same error result (except the error would reference "UPDATE" instead of "MERGE".) If it's the same circumstances and doesn't error, it will bring more attention to MERGE itself rather than some combination of client+connection+whatever. Your MERGE looks fine, so something else is plausible. Can you try a different client, e.g., System i Navigator?

Comment: @user2338816 are you saying the same thing can be accomplished with an UPDATE statement ? If so how would I fashion such a query ? The connection is not an issue as it does run other commands including UPDATE but I am using a JDBC driver via Squirrel SQL Client until I am able to get access via client access screen.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. (But I see no reason an UPDATE couldn't work.) The MERGE **should** work but doesn't. The statement possibly isn't the problem, but we can't see exactly what you see. If you try the MERGE statement and it fails, then select the MERGE statement text and replace it with an UPDATE that won't affect anything if it runs, the success or failure will tell us a lot about what's going on. But it would need to run in the 'exact' same place as the failing MERGE.

Comment: Since an UPDATE should be all that's needed, I assumed you had some purpose in mind for using MERGE instead.

Comment: @user2338816 I replaced just the word MERGE with UPDATE. I got the error 
`Error: [SQL0199] Keyword USING not expected. Valid tokens: SET.
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -199`

Comment: @user2338816 If you are saying an update is all that is needed could you please help me fashion a query that only uses UPDATE and achieves the comparison criteria required ? My reason for using MERGE is my limited knowledge on hw to fashion the query using UPDATE only which you say is possible

Comment: The MERGE should work and an answer should be found for your problem. Giving an UPDATE to do it will practically invalidate the question you asked and really should be in a separate question. Replacing "MERGE" with "UPDATE" is a good test, but an actual working UPDATE needs to be run. It should have a WHERE clause that ensures no rows will really be affected. If it succeeds, the real answer is probably to report the problem to IBM. It needs to be fixed, and the eventual fix should be added here as an 'Answer' for others to refer to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's now known to be 6.1, we know that MERGE isn't appropriate and a straight UPDATE could be used. Simplest might be:

```
update AB27PR AB
   set AB.XREADSTAT = 1
where AB.XREADSTAT = 0
  and exists( select SR.QREADSTAT
                from S490JR SR
                where AB.USER = SR.USER
                  AND AB.XCCOMP = SR.ROCOMP
                  AND AB.XEFID = SR.REFID
                  AND SR.QREADSTAT = 1 )
```

Since AB.XREADSTAT will always receive a (1) value from table S490JR, it can be supplied as a constant. The only requirement is that a properly matching row should 'exist' in S490JR.

A more general UPDATE that would cover conditions that aren't needed here could look like:

```
update AB27PR AB
   set AB.XREADSTAT = ( select max( SR.QREADSTAT )
                          from S490JR SR
                          where AB.USER = SR.USER
                            AND AB.XCCOMP = SR.ROCOMP
                            AND AB.XEFID = SR.REFID
                            AND SR.QREADSTAT = 1 )
where AB.XREADSTAT = 0
  and exists( select SR.QREADSTAT
                from S490JR SR
                where AB.USER = SR.USER
                  AND AB.XCCOMP = SR.ROCOMP
                  AND AB.XEFID = SR.REFID
                  AND SR.QREADSTAT = 1 )
```

In that case, it pulls whatever value is in SR.QREADSTAT. Of course, since the WHERE clause limits the value to (1), it's still the only possible result for the SET clause.

Also, the MAX() function is used in order to handle the possibility that there might be multiple rows in S490JR that satisfy the WHERE conditions. (We don't know what every row in your table contains.) The result set of the sub-select of the SET clause can only contain a single row. Only a single value can fit into the SET column. The MAX() function ensures a single value even though that value might be in multiple matching rows. The MIN() function could also be used in place of MAX(). (I'd like SQL to have something like an ANY() function, but the SQL standard used for 6.1 simply has nothing like that.)

Note that in both examples the subselect needs to condition the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement itself. You want to be sure to update only "matching" rows.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, the system is actually running OS 6.1 which does not support MERGE.